# How to customize the reference ranges for both \cref and \labelcref simultaneously?

Tags: cleveref

Feeding `pdflatex` with

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
%% customizing: “Formula” instead of “Eq.”, “Formulas” instead of “Eqs.”, and allow for line breaks wherever we can.
\crefname{equation}{Formula}{Formulas}
\Crefname{equation}{Formula}{Formulas}
\crefformat{equation}{Formula (#2#1#3)}
\Crefformat{equation}{Formula (#2#1#3)}
\creflabelformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{Formulas (#3#1#4) to (#5#2#6)}
\Crefrangeformat{equation}{Formulas (#3#1#4) to (#5#2#6)}
\crefrangelabelformat{equation}{(#3#1#4) to (#5#2#6)}
\crefmultiformat{equation}{Formulas (#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}{, (#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}
\Crefmultiformat{equation}{Formulas (#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}{, (#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}
\labelcrefmultiformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}{, (#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}
\crefrangemultiformat{equation}{Formulas (#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}{, (#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}
\Crefrangemultiformat{equation}{Formulas (#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}{, (#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}
\labelcrefrangemultiformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}{, (#2#1#3)}{ and (#2#1#3)}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  1\label{one}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  2\label{two}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  3\label{three}
\end{equation}
References with the name: \cref{one,two,three}.\\
References without the name: \labelcref{one,two,three}.
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: output]

How do we set up cleveref in the preamble to get

> (1) to (3)

instead of

> 1 to 3

also for the reference range without the cross-reference name (here, “Formulas“)? Notice that we do want to allow for line breaks directly after “Formula” and “Formulas”.

Comment: Aside: `\creflabelformat{equation}{(#2#1#3)}` and all other `\cref...format` directives are missing an important ingredient: The fact that the equation number and its encasing parentheses should always be typeset in upright lettering. Hence, do write `\creflabelformat{equation}{\textup{(#2#1#3)}}`, etc.

Comment: @Mico Any reference to the style? We might use a `\labecref{…}` or a `\cref{…}` also in the scope of a `\emph{…}`, or a `\textit{…}`, or a `\begin{theorem}…\end{theorem}`. Our non-minimal example is in German anyway. I've never heard of such a rule as you mention for “The Awful German Language” (© Mark Twain) .